# msg.sender vs owner

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, msg.sender

Is it bad practice (or risk prone) to use `owner` instead of `msg.sender` when checking actions initiated by a caller?

...even if I check that `owner` is authorized by `msg.sender` to do the mentioned actions? Like for example:

```js
sender --> Contract A --> Contract B
```

In this case, the final state changes that affect `sender` are done in Contract `B`, but `sender` calls first Contract `A`, which in turn calls Contract `B`.

So `msg.sender` in Contract `B` would be Contract `A`, which would be acting on behalf of `sender`.

If Contract `A` gets the proper authorizations from `sender`, is there a risk of an exploit here?

P.S. I'm purposely avoiding `tx.origin` due to its risky behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `owner`? There is no `owner` property in EVM.

Comment: It's just semantics. `owner` is the owner of the tokens that are being transacted in the tx, which can differ from `msg.sender` depending on the context @ashhanai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should limit the access to **Contract B**'s functions to only be *calleable* by **Contract A**. Respectively, you check whether the `msg.sender` is an authorized entity in **Contract A**, call **Contract B** if he is, and revert if not.

You should apply a design pattern like **"Prop drilling"** here, because Solidity doesn't have a *secure* alternative for that.

For example:

```
    pragma solidity ^0.8.13;
    
    contract A {
        mapping(address => bool) private whitelistedSender;
        B private immutable b = new B();
    
        constructor() {
    
        }
    
        modifier whitelisted() {
            require(whitelistedSender[msg.sender], "Not whitelisted");
            _;
        }
    
        function doSomethingFirst() external whitelisted {
            b.mint(msg.sender);
        }
    
        function whitelistSomeoneElse(address whom) external whitelisted {
            whitelistedSender[whom] = true;
        }
    }
    
    contract B {
        address private immutable owner;
    
        constructor() {
            owner = msg.sender;
        }
    
        modifier auth() {
            require(msg.sender == owner, "You are not authorized to call this function");
            _;
        }
    
        function mint(address user) external auth {
            this;
        }
    
    }
    
    contract Test {
        // access B functions through the A contract here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **owner** in the context of authorization is generally a safer practice compared to **tx.origin**. While both concepts involve determining the origin of a transaction, they have distinct characteristics and associated security risks.

**owner vs. tx.origin:**

```
1. owner:
```

Typically refers to the **owner** or **administrator** of a smart contract, often set during contract deployment.
Used for authorization checks within the contract.
More controlled and less prone to certain security vulnerabilities compared to tx.origin.

```
2. tx.origin:
```

Represents the original external actor that triggered the transaction.
Can be manipulated in the presence of proxy contracts, making it risky for authorization.
Prone to security risks, especially in scenarios involving multi-contract interactions.

**Why Prefer owner Over tx.origin:**

- Predictable Authorization: Using **owner** for authorization checks within the contract provides a more predictable and controlled environment.
- Avoiding Proxy Exploits: Unlike **tx.origin**, which can be manipulated by proxy contracts, **owner** is typically set during contract deployment and remains constant.
- Consistent Security Model: Leveraging owner aligns with standard access control patterns, such as Ownable, which is widely recognized for its security benefits.